# Wordpress White Screen of Death after activate own theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create my new own theme for wordpress (and the first one) and I encounter that my site isn't loading the header nor the content of index.php. It's pretty strange, I've read the WP WSoD documentation but I couldn't find anything helpful since my theme only have a couple of lines, I don't see the problem.

This is my theme structure:
[image]

And I've only edited `index.php`, `header.php` and `footer.php`. My `functions.php` seems to have something but I just added some lines to test, it's now blank again.

And this is what's inside my `header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?> </title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Natural Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/style.css">

        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/favicon.png"/>
    </head>
    <body>
```

This is what's inside my `footer.php`:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/popper.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is what I've inside my `index.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php while( have_posts() ) the_post(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: By looking at the code, there's nothing to display.

Comment: It should load the title and the font code should be visible in the browser, and it isn't doing it.

Comment: Why are you adding = after opening php tag, href="<?= it should be href="<?php

Comment: It's a php's shorthand...

Comment: Yes, check php.ini, shorthand should be enable by default, but sometimes it won't. Otherwise turn on debugging from wp-config.php.

Comment: Also try adding <?php wp_head(); ?> before closing head tag, and <?php wp_footer(); ?> before closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

I edited `index.php` and WordPress was loading `front-page.php`